# How to place a layout completely on top of keyboard in bottom sheet dialog fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, dialog, bottom-sheet

I have a `bottom sheet dialog fragment` in an `Activity`. When the `softkeyboard` is shown I need to push the complete `dialog fragment layout` to the top of `keyboard`.

I have tried various ways like using `GRAVITY.TOP` , `bottomMargin` for the `dialog` increasing the height etc.

None of the above ways are working. I want to make the top of `bottom sheet dialog fragment` align with the `parent` i.e top of phone.

Since I am using `Framelayout` to add `Bottom Sheet Dialog fragment` in `activity` I am unable to set `alignParentTopAttribute` . Please let me know if there are any ways of doing this or suggestions to achieve this.

Please find below code that I have tried till now:

```
view?.viewTreeObserver?.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
    var r = Rect()
    view?.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r)
    var screenHeight = view?.rootView?.height
    var initialHeight = rootLayout.height
    var keyPadHeight = screenHeight?.minus(r.bottom)

    var layoutParams: Frame.LayoutParams = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    )
    if (keyPadHeight!! > screenHeight?.times(0.15)!!) {// 0.15 ratio is perhaps enough to determine keypad height.
        // keyboard is opened
        if (!isKeyboardShowing) {
            isKeyboardShowing = true
        }
        var window: Window? = dialog?.window
        var windowManagerLayoutParams: WindowManager.LayoutParams? = window?.attributes
       //Tried this
        windowManagerLayoutParams.gravity = GRAVITY.TOP
        window.attributes = windowManagerLayoutParams

       //Tried this
       layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP
       rootLayout.layoutParams = layoutParams
    } else {
        // keyboard is closed
        if (isKeyboardShowing) {
            isKeyboardShowing = false
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried `adjustResize` and `stateVisible` in `manifest`. `adjustResize` will not push complete `layout` to the top of `soft keyboard`, there will be a `scroll` behind the `soft keyboard`, user will have to `scroll` to see the complete `layout`.
But I do not want to have the scroll, user should see the complete layout on top of the `soft keyboard` as soon as it is visible.